What is the difference between "Donald Trump just got shot at!" and "Donald Trump just got shot!"?
(i) Donald Trump  just got shot at!
(ii) Donald Trump  just got shot!
I saw a tweet with the former text but it was edited as the later then.

This question is similar to: Shoot, Shoot At. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can shoot someone or you can shoot at someone.

DJT was both shot and shot at. Several shots were fired, only one of which one hit Trump but others caused fatalities.

@WeatherVane Unclear, but it seems he was not shot (= hit by a bullet), but rather nicked by flying glass from the teleprompter. A quibble, but it's a question about a quibble.

For many years, ending a sentence with a preposition was considered poor English.  So #1 would be rejected.  But over time as the language perpetually is dumbed down to the lowest common denominator, what used to be mark of a poor education becomes ignored, rationalized, and then accepted.     Eventually we will all speak in emoticons. :-)

@RussellBorogove that information has surfaced since the initial report, which was that a bullet nicked his ear.

@Joe: How do you propose amending "Donald Trump just got shot at" to avoid ending the sentence with a preposition? It can't be done. The rule was always ridiculous, and ignored by anybody with a feel for the English language.

I don't propose amending it.  I propose removing the "at" as the person who edited it did.  As for the rule, mostly it was ignored by people who didn't pay attention in English class.

Or if the shade of meaning is critical to you, then, "Someone shot at Donald Trump". No need to use passive.

@Joe I direct you to Churchill's wisdom on the subject of prepositions (with which you are probably familiar, but I'll take any excuse).
Personally I would take issue with the word 'got'. It's unnecessary, it adds the implication that the shooting may have been accidental or even self-inflicted, and it makes the speaker sound uneducated.

@Joe: Does Shakespeare count as poor English in your estimation? Just in Hamlet's soliloquy, we have (i) "The heart-ache, and the thousand natural shocks /
That Flesh is heir to"; and (ii) "And makes us rather bear those ills we have, /
Than fly to others that we know not of?"

When the guy who says, "Donald Trump got shot at" starts writing in iambic pentameter, we'll talk.

To say that someone "shot at" someone else is to say that the first person fired a gun with the intention of hitting the other person.  It does not mean that he hit the other.
To say that someone "got shot" is an informal way to say that he "was shot."  This indicates that he was actually hit.

Even further: the "got shot" doesn't necessarily mean someone fired a gun with the intention of hitting the other person.

Even further than that, shooting doesn't even imply using a gun, just something that fires a projectile. I'm not sure if a trebuchet or catapult fall into that category,  but a bow and arrow, slingshot, and straw and spitball do. You can even shoot someone with a rubberband and your finger.

@computercarguy: Your point, while correct, is the same for both options, so it's not relevant. By comparison, Opifex' point is distinctly different between "shot at" (which implies intent) and "shot" (which does not).

@computercarguy To remove your uncertainty, trebuchets and catapults do shoot, as does anything that uses mechanical advantage to launch a missile. The distinction is with weapons that use chemical combustion (guns, rockets, arquebuses..) - those fire. Thus, anyone who says fire an arrow is committing a greater sin than splitting an infinitive.

To say He got shot at means that a person with a gun (or people with guns) took aim at him, or pointed their gun(s) at him, and fired at least once.  They shot at him. He got shot at.
While being shot at, a person may get shot, i.e. struck by a bullet.

Reason for the downvote?  Or do you just prefer to take pot-shots?

+1 Yes . They are taking pot-shots. Your answer mentions "shot at" doesn't mean "not hit".

shot at is silent with respect to whether the person is hit or not. It refers simply to the situation of incoming bullets from guns intentionally pointed at the person.  A person who is struck by a builet was not necessarily being shot at, and a person who is being shot at is not necessarily struck and not necessarily not struck. The person may be struck and may be missed.

I would argue that being shot at doesn't imply anyone actually aimed at you as the intended target. "I shot at x." That usually implies I aimed at x. However, it doesn't have to. Also, "X was shot at" could be a stray bullet was headed their way in say, a cross fire. "At" is a preposition. Which means the action/verb is only dependent on the position off the subject, not the intention of the actor.

@DataMinion  If a  stray bullet is whizzing past you, you are not being shot at.   You might think you are, and say that you are, but you aren't.

@TimR, the proposition at is position relative. My position and the proximity of the bullet means I was shot at. The shooter's intention does not matter. To demonstrate this, towards and at can be used interchangeably. Being shot at can mean the same thing as someone shooting towards you. Position relative to the subject. That's what a preposition does. Intent doesn't matter. A bullet was coming AT me. Does that mean it was aimed at me? NO. It DOES NOT. And "A bullet was coming towards me" means the same thing ats "a bullet was coming at me. SAME thing. No intent needed.

@DataMinion I have to disagree again.   Someone who accidentally hit you with a bullet didn't "shoot at you".  If he was aiming at a moose, missed, and the bullet traveled through the brush and struck you, he could say "I didn't even know you were there. You weren't wearing day-glo orange and I didn't see   you. I wasn't shooting at you. " And you, once you know that he didn't even see you, would be wrong to say "He was shooting at me" as that would be misleading. You'd say "in my direction".

@TimR, again, you are using your own bias while maintaining the idea that at absolutely and always implies intent. It does NOT. Nor does it have to. Can it? Yes. Can doesn't mean has to. The writer isn't always implying anything. The reader is. ... using their OWN conscious or unconscious bias.

@TimR. "A car came at me" is an acceptable sentence. Does that imply it was intentionally driven to run me over? Look at one of the definitions of "at": "expressing location or arrival in a particular place or position." "I live at a shelter." Did I intend to live there? Maybe maybe not. A shelter is certainly not many people's intended target to live. Now let's change the words around. "X shot at a person." Why do I not have to intend on living somewhere, yet that shooter had to intend on something? Same type of sentence with no verbs, nouns etc changing position in those sentences.

@DataMinion No, I'm simply using the locution "shoot at" in its standard meaning, and you are engaging is an abstruse  argument about the deictic nature of the locative preposition at.

The first one means someone aimed at Trump and shot.
The second one means he was indeed hit, which was actually what happened. The text was hence revised.

To shot at is not direction. It is a target.

Thanks,  @Lambie.  Agreed.

A minor quibble: 'he was shot' typically means a more substantial impact. I would call what happened as being 'grazed' by a bullet (if that's actually what hit the edge of his ear.) Saying he was 'shot' seems like an exaggeration.

Thanks, @JimmyJames.  Agreed. That would be a word-choice question.

@JimmyJames in legal terms, being shot and grazed suffer the same outcome for the shooter. Also, one can be shot and not grazed by a bullet. But one can't be grazed by a bullet, and not shot. Symantecs. Either way, the question about shot and shot at is irrelevant to Trump being shot and grazed. Notice I said shot and grazed. And. Can't be or. You can't be shot or grazed.

@DataMinion This is an ELL stack, not the legal stack. It's helpful to someone learning English to understand that the saying someone was shot has implies a serious injury. Yes, technically being grazed is being shot but the fact remains that in normal everyday conversation, the term 'grazed' is much more appropriate than 'shot' for what happened. Also 'Symantec' is a company name. 'Semantics' is the English word.

Adding a wrinkle: "Got shot" does not absolutely require intent or aiming. A bystander can "get shot" when the shooter was aiming at someone else.
There's a scene in the movie "True Lies" in which a machine gun was dropped. Many people "got shot" (and killed) because the gun fired on its own as it tumbled down a stairway. So, no person was the shooter, but many people got shot.

I love the "True Lies" reference. That's a great scene. Also, we have to remember that shooting something doesn't necessarily involve a gun. You can shoot someone with a slingshot, bow and arrow, or even a straw and a spitball. As an aside, my friend April Jennifer Choi uses a 30 ft whip to trigger a compound bow to shoot an arrow with a broadhead at herself so she can catch the arrow barehanded. She sometimes does this blindfolded, too.

I'm going to upvote this simply because I argued this point as a reply in another answer before seeing yours. A preposition doesn't need intent from the actor. Only the position of the subject. I don't care who was aiming at who, if a bullet comes my way, I'm going to say I was shot at. Because at in that context is dependent on my position, not the one who was aimed at. Aimed at has a different subject than I, and the position there is the actor (shooter).

@DataMinion This answer doesn't even address "shot at" and acknowledges that fact by calling it "a wrinkle". It focuses on "get shot". So   talking about the preposition is out in left field here.  As I say in the answer that you commented on, "get shot" means "struck by a bullet" -- nothing about intent or aiming.

@TimR no, it's not out in left field. Many accepted answers mention to be shot at means to be aimed at. It doesn't. Doesn't it FULLY answer the question, probable not. But it DOES help clarify at least half of that question. Just because some were pointed out being wrong about the aiming part DOESN'T MEAN YOU GET TO GO AROUND SAYING EVERYONE IS IN LEFT FIELD. aiming is IRRELEVANT. Did you say to others their aiming answers were in left field too? No., You DID NOT. Because they support your idea that aiming is implied or needed.

@DataMinion I said your bringing up the preposition at is out in left field as a comment left here, in an answer that doesn't talk about "shot at" but only about  "got shot".

You can shoot someone or you can shoot at someone.
That man shot at John. [doesn't mean he hit him, he aimed at him and fired his weapon]
That man shot John. [John was hit by a bullet fired at him.]

Those kids spent the afternoon shooting rats in the basement with a beebee gun. [They hit them]

Those kids spent the afternoon shooting at rats in the basements. [The rats were the target]


